# regex. Find multiple occurrence of pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

```
my_string = "this data is F56 F23 and G87"
```

And I would like to use regex to return the following output

```
['F56 F23', 'G87']
```

So basically, I'm interested in returning all the parts of the string that start with either F or G and are followed by two numbers. In addition, if there are multiple consecutive occurrences I would like regex to group them together.

I approached the problem with python and with this code

```
import re
re.findall(r'\b(F\d{2}|G\d{2})\b', my_string)
```

I was able to get all the occurrences

```
['F56', 'F23', 'G87']
```

But I would like to have the first two groups together since they are consecutive occurrences. Any ideas of how I can achieve that?

Comment: yep, I mean that there's just one white space between them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\b[FG]\d{2}(?:\s+[FG]\d{2})*\b
```

Non-capturing group `(?:\s+[FG]\d{2})*` will find zero or more of the following space separated F/G substrings.

**Code:**

```
>>> my_string = "this data is F56 F23 and G87"
>>> re.findall(r'\b[FG]\d{2}(?:\s+[FG]\d{2})*\b', my_string)
['F56 F23', 'G87']
```

Answer (score 3):

> So basically, I'm interested in returning all the parts of the string that start with either F or G and are followed by two numbers. In addition, if there are multiple **consecutive occurrences** I would like regex to group them together.

You can do this with:

```
\b(?:[FG]\d{2})(?:\s+[FG]\d{2})*\b
```

in case it is separated by *at least one spacing character*. If that is not a requirement, you can do this with:

```
\b(?:[FG]\d{2})(?:\s*[FG]\d{2})*\b
```

Both the first and second regex generate:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b(?:[FG]\d{2})(?:\s+[FG]\d{2})*\b',my_string)
['F56 F23', 'G87']
>>> re.findall(r'\b(?:[FG]\d{2})(?:\s*[FG]\d{2})*\b',my_string)
['F56 F23', 'G87']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print map(lambda x : x[0].strip(), re.findall(r'((\b(F\d{2}|G\d{2})\b\s*)+)', my_string))
```

change your regex to r'((\b(F\d{2}|G\d{2})\b\s*)+)' (brackets around, /s* to find all, that are connected by whitespaces, a + after the last bracket to find more than one occurance (greedy)

now you have a list of lists, of which you need every 0th Argument. You can use **map** and **lambda** for this. To kill last blanks I used **strip()**